# MVC4, two different masterpage

Tags: asp.net, layout, asp.net-mvc-4, master-pages

How can I use two different master page or layout in my web project with mvc4?

Comment: Well, just use them - create two master pages and specify either of them for Layout in your child pages. What's the actual problem you have?

Comment: Master pages are an asp.net concept. You want layout views.

Comment: Why would you want 2 different master pages?

Comment: You might think, there are two different designs. Some of the pages of the first Master Page, the second of the others. How to create two different layout?

Comment: Just like any other layout. The file goes in views/shared and then reference with the `Layout` property of the child views.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You create 2 different Layouts and then inside your view you can choose which layout to use:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml";
}
```

This can also be done inside the controller action rendering the view:

```
return View("Index", "MyLayout", myViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to be an expert in MVC.  As a matter of fact, I just started using it.
This is what I did.  I copied Site.Master using Windows Explorer, renamed it, added it to Shared Views, edited it, and started using it. Worked for me.